# Routes parameters are interchangeable

Tags: php, laravel

I have in my View:

```
<a href="/agents/{{ $property->user_id }}/{{ $property->id }}/edit" class="btn-sm">Edit</a></td>
```

But when I put 1-50 in my $property->**user_id** parameter, it leads to a property.

I have `Route::get('/agents/{agent}/{id}/edit', 'AgentController@edit');` in my `web.php` file.

**Route File:**

```
Route::get('/properties/', 'PropertyController@index'); 
Route::get('/properties/{property}', 'PropertyController@show'); 
Route::get('/agents/{agent}', 'AgentController@index'); 
Route::get('/agents/{agent}/{id}/edit', 'AgentController@edit'); 
Route::post('/agents/{agent}', 'AgentController@update')->name('agent.property.update');
```

This is my Controller code:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $property = Property::find($id);

        return view('agents.edit', compact('property'));
    }
```

I don't understand this behavior in Laravel, it's not what I intend and I just want to make the route work correctly.

Comment: Hello again lagbox. The order of the route parameters not being reflected. The problem is, I can go in and type in "1" for my agent parameter and a property will pop up.

Comment: what do you mean "a property will pop up"?

Comment: A record from my properties table will display.

Comment: if that url matches that route then that controller method is returning a Property as it is written to do ... if that is the route definition which uses that controller method then `$id` is what would be the `'{agent}'` part of that path

Comment: is there a way that I can also make the agent apart of the first parameter of route concretely?

Comment: sorry, i am not sure what you mean by that, if you can rephrase your intentions I can try to explain what you need

Comment: i mean, is there a way that I can lock in the first {agent} parameter so that way it will not display a property, but be the authenticated user.

Comment: Show us all your route file content.

Comment: lets restart ... because of the parameters for that route I would assume that controller method would be for editing a property that belongs to a particular agent, `{agent}/{property}` ... is that correct?

Comment: Route::get('/properties/', 'PropertyController@index');
Route::get('/properties/{property}', 'PropertyController@show'); Route::get('/agents/{agent}', 'AgentController@index');
Route::get('/agents/{agent}/{id}/edit', 'AgentController@edit');
Route::post('/agents/{agent}', 'AgentController@update')->name('agent.property.update');

Comment: yes that is correct lagbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel gives both agent_id and property_id to the controller as parameter. You are using agent_id only and assuming it as property id.

```
public function edit($agent_id, $property_id)
{
    $property = Property::find($property_id);
    return view('agents.edit', compact('property'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this solution displays the error even for routes that I'm authorized to go in. So I can't edit properties where property->user_id == auth()->id();

Comment: No, that was untrue, I have my logic wrong. Still checking my database now. Sorry about confusion.

Comment: Right now, Laravel is taking property with the id of 12 and displaying it in place of my agent id which is equal to 12 as well.

Comment: what is the URL you are hitting?

Comment: Route::get('/agents/{agent}/{property}/edit', 'AgentController@edit')->name('agent.property.edit');

Comment: <a href="/agents/{{ $property->user_id }}/{{ $property->id }}/edit"

Comment: Made some changes in the answer, please check.

Comment: All I had to do was pass in the agent_id, but removed the agent_id check and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but if you remove agent_id check, anyone can edit property.

Comment: But if I have it in place, it gives me a "Bad Request" every property

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route file, I think you should put this route:

```
Route::get('/agents/{agent}/{id}/edit', 'AgentController@edit');
```

above this one:

```
Route::get('/agents/{agent}', 'AgentController@index');
```